Error while Converting Synchronous Action Filter to Asynchronous in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I have developed a synchronous action filter for an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. Recently, I converted this action filter to an asynchronous version.
However, during validation, I encountered the following error:

If an IAsyncActionFilter provides a result value by setting the Result property of ActionExecutingContext to a non-null value, then it cannot call the next filter by invoking ActionExecutionDelegate.

Here goes the code details - before changes:
DemoFilter.cs:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DemoFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly RoleEnumType[] AllowedRoles;

    public DemoFilter(params RoleEnumType[] arrRoles)
    {
        if (arrRoles == null || !arrRoles.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception("No role passed to check.");
        }
        AllowedRoles = arrRoles;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext objContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!objContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                objContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                return;
            }
            
            UserInfoRes userinfo = GetUserDetails(objContext.HttpContext.User.GetEmail().ToLower());

            if (userinfo == null || !AllowedRoles.Contains(userinfo.RoleId.ToEnum<RoleEnumType>()))
            {
                objContext.Result = new BadRequestResult();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

After changes - DemoFilter.cs:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DemoFilter(params RoleEnumType[] arrRoles) : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly RoleEnumType[] _arrRoles = arrRoles.IsNotNull();

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Throw error in case context is null
        context.ThrowIfNull(nameof(context));

        // Get instance of ILogger
        ILogger logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger>().IsNotNull();

        try
        {
            await ValidateUserRoleAsync(context, logger);

            await next(); // Proceed to the next action filter or action method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while executing the AllowRoles filter.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task ValidateUserRoleAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        // Check if the user is authenticated
        if (!(context.HttpContext.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated).GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            // Log a warning using the provided logger
            logger.Warning($"Unauthorized request: User is not authenticated.");

            // Set the result of the action context to a UnauthorizedObjectResult with the error message
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult("Unauthorized request: User is not authenticated");
            return;
        }

        // Get user details based on email and userLocationId
        var userInfo = await userValidationRepository.GetLoggedInUserDetailsAsync1(email, userLocationId);

        if (userInfo is null || !_arrRoles.Contains(userInfo.RoleId.ToEnum<RoleEnumType>()))
        {
            // Log a warning using the provided logger
            logger.Warning("User with email address: {email} does not have the required roles.", email);

            // Set the result of the action context to a BadRequestObjectResult with the error message
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult($"User with email address: {email} does not have the required roles.");
            return;
        }
    }
}

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

Maybe try if (context.Result == null) await next(); alternatively return a Task<bool> from ValidateUserRoleAsync indicaiting whether to continue.

Thanks @Charlieface for your response.  I want to know is it ok to to comment or remove await next(). Will it have any other impact?

Well no, it's what decides whether to pass it on to the next handler. You need some kind of logic to decide whether to pass it on, like I said.

You mean the result it got from first filter will be passed to next filter in this case? Or will it stop executing other filters that are applied on the action method

That depends on what logic you want. You can put whatever you like in that if statement, I was just suggesting a way to detect whether a result has been provided (because no point continuing on if so).

@Charlieface - I noticed one more thing. The OnActionExecutionAsync execution happens successfully with commented code ( await next();) but there is no response from the action method. In short the action method returns a empty response with HTTP Status Code : 200.

Yes that's what I keep telling you, don't comment it out, I'm not sure what you are having difficulty with. The await next() passes the request on to the next handler, but if you have already set the response then this doesn't make sense. So you want to check first if (context.Result == null) await next(); If you comment it out then the other handlers are not executed and the request won't be returned correctly.

@Charlieface - Thanks for your help. Finally everything worked for me as expected :)
